# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' while trying to fetch data from json in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the element from json array based on the filter condition.

```
List correctList = [];
String qtn = 'What is the capital of USA';    
if(qtn.toLowerCase().contains('capital')) {
  correctList = countries.where((country) => country['name'].toLowerCase().contains(qtn.split(' ').last.toLowerCase())).toList();
}
```

and countries is a json array fetched from an api, this is the first element of json array for reference:

```
List countries = [{"name":"Afghanistan","topLevelDomain":[".af"],"alpha2Code":"AF","alpha3Code":"AFG","callingCodes":["93"],"capital":"Kabul","altSpellings":["AF","Afġānistān"],"region":"Asia","subregion":"Southern Asia","population":27657145,"latlng":[33.0,65.0],"demonym":"Afghan","area":652230.0,"gini":27.8,"timezones":["UTC+04:30"],"borders":["IRN","PAK","TKM","UZB","TJK","CHN"],"nativeName":"افغانستان","numericCode":"004","currencies":[{"code":"AFN","name":"Afghan afghani","symbol":"؋"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"ps","iso639_2":"pus","name":"Pashto","nativeName":"پښتو"},{"iso639_1":"uz","iso639_2":"uzb","name":"Uzbek","nativeName":"Oʻzbek"},{"iso639_1":"tk","iso639_2":"tuk","name":"Turkmen","nativeName":"Türkmen"}],"translations":{"de":"Afghanistan","es":"Afganistán","fr":"Afghanistan","ja":"アフガニスタン","it":"Afghanistan","br":"Afeganistão","pt":"Afeganistão","nl":"Afghanistan","hr":"Afganistan","fa":"افغانستان"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg","regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"SAARC","name":"South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}],"cioc":"AFG"}]
```

I tried this piece of code in DartPad and it worked fine but When I am trying this in flutter it is throwing the mentioned exception.

Comment: Try adding types: `List<Map<String,dynamic>> correctList = [];` and `List<Map<String,dynamic>> countries`.

Comment: Also inside `if` create a variable `final countryName = qtn.split(' ').last.toLowerCase();` and pass in into `contains()` to not repeat this step.